# 3 column layout with interchangeable divs

Tags: css, html, layout

I have been trying to create a 3 column layout with divs but I haven't found any way to do the following:

[image]

I haven't found any info on how to do this. Basically I want the divs to be able to be added in any order and have the margins the same.

Comment: I take it you aren't building this with a small-screen first approach. Are these actually being dynamically injected or is this just a theoretical issue you are working with? I would check out masonry or something - that might be helpful, http://masonry.desandro.com/ otherwise, you are going to have to create a set of rules for this. Can you think up a set of rules in plain english for this? That would be a good start... "if 100%, no margin, but if 33%, margin only on the right if etc etc etc... What is the real use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Twitter Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) is especially suited for this type of layout. If you want more specific help, please provide some code on what you've already tried.

Comment: I've tried using inline blocks with percentage widths and margins, filler divs for margins(so margins aren't duplicated), but I don't know what else to try. I've looked extensively for other solutions but haven't found any. I thought about floats but they seem to have problems and I don't want to have to clear the floats.

Comment: You won't have to clear the floats if you wrap them properly, for example by placing `overflow:hidden;` on the wrapping element. If you don't want to use Twitter Bootstrap, you can do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/L9X9F/1/

Comment: This is a really good example. Is there any way you could do this with percent(or some other way to scale with screen size?)

Comment: Thank You! Whenever I use percentages they always end up a little off. Your example ends up with a tiny difference in width, but only on the inside, not the edges.

Comment: Is there any way to make the x-axis increase only?